# CiviMobileAPI - "The extension is too old" Error

Tags: wordpress, extension, mobile

I'm running CiviCRM (v5.21.2) and the CiviMobileAPI (v5.0.1) extension in WordPress (v5.3.2).

The CiviMobileAPI extension path is `/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/com.agiliway.civimobileapi/`

The CiviCRM WP REST API (v0.1) WordPress extension is also installed and active.

Still, I'm getting a "The extension is too old" Error when connecting via the iOS CiviMobile app (v5.0).

What could be the reason for that?

Answer (score 0):

[The CiviMobileAPI page](https://civicrm.org/extensions/civimobileapi) is mentioning that you need a Patch for Wordpress - maybe that's the reason?

Comment: Thanks. AFAIK the The CiviCRM WP REST API (v0.1) WordPress extension IS the patch you mentioned, it's already active.

Comment: Update: I made an identical WP+CiviCRM test installation on another server. There, CiviMobileAPI works just fine. Now I only have to find out what's wrong with the existing server or installation...